# WIX how to hold up install if user doesnt select any options

Tags: wix

I create a custom WIX screen in which the user is to turn on or off some options.  If they chose to uncheck all of the options, I do not want to allow the install to continue.

My Wix UI look like this:

```
<UI>
            <Dialog Id="SelectConfigureServicesDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Choose Services">
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>                      

                <Control Id="ConfigurationServicesCheckbox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="17" Property="INSTALLCONFIGURATIONSERVICES" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="!(loc.SELECTCONFIGURE_CONFIGSERVICE_NAME)" />
                <Control Id="AuthenicationServicesCheckbox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="80" Width="290" Height="17" Property="INSTALLAUTHENICATIONSERVICES" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="!(loc.SELECTCONFIGURE_AUTHSERVICE_NAME)" />
                <Control Id="AgentDesktopCommunicatorServicesCheckbox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="100" Width="290" Height="17" Property="INSTALLAGENTDESKTOPCOMMUNICATORSERVICES" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="!(loc.SELECTCONFIGURE_COMMUNICATOR_NAME)" />
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
```

I'm not sure how I can test that at least one of the check boxes is selected before allowing the user to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Condition under the Next control element.

```
      <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[SomeProperty1 = 1]]></Condition>
      <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[SomeProperty2 = 1]]></Condition>
      <Condition Action="show"><![CDATA[SomeProperty3 = 1]]></Condition>
```

In that case the next button will be disabled until one of the checkbox is selected.

You can also check the code of the default license dialog by wix.

```
<Fragment>
    <UI>
        <Dialog Id="LicenseAgreementDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlg_Title)">
            <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgBannerBitmap)" />
            <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
            <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
            <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgDescription)" />
            <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgTitle)" />
            <Control Id="LicenseAcceptedCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="207" Width="330" Height="18" CheckBoxValue="1" Property="LicenseAccepted" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgLicenseAcceptedCheckBox)" />
            <Control Id="Print" Type="PushButton" X="112" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIPrint)">
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula">1</Publish>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
            <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
                <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
                <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[LicenseAccepted <> "1"]]></Condition>
                <Condition Action="enable">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Condition>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="140" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">
                <Text SourceFile="!(wix.WixUILicenseRtf=$(var.licenseRtf))" />
            </Control>
        </Dialog>
    </UI>
</Fragment>
```